# Python at AWS Lambda: `requests` from botocore.vendored deprecated, but `requests` not available

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

I've got a Python script for an AWS Lambda function that does HTTP POST requests to another endpoint. Since Python's `urllib2.request`, https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html, can only handle data in the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format and I want to post JSON data, I used the Requests library, https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.7.0/.

That Requests library wasn't available at AWS Lambda in the Python runtime environment, so had to be imported via `from botocore.vendored import requests`. So far, so good.

Today, I get a deprecation warning on that:

```
DeprecationWarning: You are using the post() function from 'botocore.vendored.requests'.
This is not a public API in botocore and will be removed in the future.
Additionally, this version of requests is out of date. We recommend you install the
requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.post() function instead.
```

This was mentioned in this blog post from AWS too: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/.

Unfortunately, changing `from botocore.vendored import requests` into `import requests` results in the following error:

```
No module named 'requests'
```

Why is `requests` not available for the Python runtime at AWS Lambda? And how can I use / import it?

Comment: Are you using serverless framework?

Comment: That's a surprising, but excellent guess. Yes, I am.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies

All you need to do is download the requests module locally, then include it in your Lambda function deployment package (ZIP archive).

Example (if all your Lambda function consisted of was a single Python module + requests module):

```
$ pip install --target ./package requests
$ cd package
$ zip -r9 ${OLDPWD}/function.zip .
$ cd $OLDPWD
$ zip -g function.zip lambda_function.py
$ aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip
```

Comment: More info: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/

Comment: This is by far the easiest and most straightforward solution, and it's the one recommended by AWS Lambda in their documentation. With three short commands, you've got your ZIP file ready for upload, which you can also upload manually if you like.

Comment: What if you are working on a windows machine ? :(

Comment: @SimonB try [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html) or just look up the Command Prompt or PowerShell counterparts to the commands above.

Answer (score 34):

I succeeded sending HTTP POST requests using the  `urllib3` library, which is available at AWS Lambda without the requirements for additional installation instructions.

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('POST',
                        url,
                        body = json.dumps(some_data_structure),
                        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        retries = False)
```

Comment: I'm getting 403 error when i use this method. Can't figure out what is the problem. Any solution?

Comment: You get 403 errors on which URL? And that error isn't present with for example `curl -X POST <your-URL>` or `curl --data "pi:3.14159265" <your-URL>`? 403 means the server understood the request, but is refusing to authorize it... so it's more likely that the problem is with your request against that endpoint than with the `urllib3` library.

Comment: The vendored versions of requests and urllib3 are no longer being used and have been replaced with a direct dependency on upstream urllib3 and requests is no longer a dependency of botocore. While these vendored dependencies are still in the botocore package they should not be used as they will be removed in the future. Any code that imports from botocore.vendored.requests.* should be updated accordingly. 

https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html

Comment: works for python 3.10 but didnt include the retries

Answer (score 9):

**Answer 2020-06-18**

I found a nice and easy way to use `requests` inside AWS Lambda functions!

Open this link and find the region that your function is using:
https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/tree/master/deployments/python3.8/arns

Open the `.csv` related to your region and search for the `requests` row.
This is the `ARN` related to `requests` library:
**arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-requests:6**

So now in your lambda function, add a layer using the ARN found.
**Obs.:** make sure your Python lambda function runtime is **python3.8**.

Comment: As owner of the repo, I approve of this comment :)

Comment: OK, that is using an AWS Lambda layer that happens to have the `requests` package installed. Instead of using a layer from an 'unknown' source, it'd be better to install the package yourself, or use an AWS-distributed layer containing that package.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/)

Specify the plugin in `serverless.yml`

```
plugins:
- serverless-python-requirements
```

At the directory root create file `requirements.txt`

**requirements.txt**

```
requests==2.22.0
```

This will install the requests and packages mentioned.

Comment: It should be clarified that this only works with the Serverless framework.

Comment: @Esteban ok will do it

Answer (score 2):

requests is NOT part of core python.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html about packaging a Lambda having external dependencies (in your case the requests library)

Comment: I know Requests isn't _in_ core Python, and thus not 'standard' available in an AWS Lambda runtime. After following AWS's advice, "We recommend you install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and ..." I ran into the (stated) problem that apparently the package isn't also available _for_ the Python runtime of AWS Lambda (at least not at the moment of writing).

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's Serverless Application Model (SAM) provides a build command that can bundle arbitrary python dependencies into the deployment artifact.

To be able to use the `requests` package in your code, add the dependency to your requirements.txt file:

```
requests==2.22.0
```

then run [`sam build`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html) to get an artifact that vendors `requests`. By default, your artifacts will be saved to the `.aws-sam/build` directory but another destination directory can be specified with the `--build-dir` option.

Consult [SAM's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-authoring.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my redneck solution that works with any library, using an AWS Lambda Layer:

This has the advantage that you don't have to trust any 3rd party layers, because you can easily make it yourself.

1. Go to your local python's Lib/site-packages (python install location or your venv)
2. Copy whichever libraries you need (e.g. "requests") into a folder named "python"
3. Zip this folder
4. Create an AWS Lambda Layer, and upload the zip into it
5. Add this layer in your lambda function
6. Import your libraries as usual, and keep coding as if nothing happened

Answer (score -10):

`pip install requests`
and then 
`import requests`
to use.

Comment: Thanks. `pip install requests` installs the library locally, but not automatically when deploying the script to AWS Lambda. So, this solution works locally, but not in AWS.