# AWS (amazon web service) Lambda function with IMB MQ python module pymqi (No module named 'pymqe')

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ibm-mq, python-3.8, pymqi

i have problem with setting up python script on aws lambda function for IBM MQ client.
The things I did:

1. I install IBM MQ client on Ubuntu linux server and there I installed pymqi with pip install pymqi
2. I zipped MQ installation path (/opt/mqm) and pymqi in same zip file
3. I uploaded this zip on AWS lambda layer
4. then I created new lambda function and add layer and wrote in function code "import pymqi"
5. In enviroment variables I added LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/mqm/lib64

I get next error: "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymqe'"

Comment: Could be how you are setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Refer to AWS documentation on how to add to it - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html - it needs to be set before the pymqi c libraries are built, and also for your lambda function.

Comment: Can you pleasae tell me what excatly do you mean? :)

Comment: When a pip install of the `pymqi` library is performed, it also creates c object code to interact with. For this compile it needs access to a c compiler, the mq c headers, and object libraries. So all have to be already on the machine, configured and locatable. So `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be already set. 

AWS like many cloud platforms limits which environment variables are inherited by spawned systems. Hence you need to read the AWS documentation on setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: You resolved this on the pymqi issues list right?   Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question: [aws lambda Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912253/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-no-module-named-requests)

This bug report on GitHub seems to be similar to your issue: https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/121

Comment: weird is because on linux machine pymqi was working, on aws is not. So I did something wrong with uploading to layer. Maybe my path was wrong. In zip file are 2 folders 1 is "python" where pymqi is installed. Second folder is "opt" where ibm mq is installed