# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'google'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-docs-api

I am writing a lambda function to create a google docs.

These are the lambda code I trying to run.

```
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def replace_placeholders(service, document_id, replacements):
    requests = []
    for placeholder, replacement in replacements.items():
        requests.append({
            'replaceAllText': {
                'containsText': {
                    'text': placeholder,
                    'matchCase': True,
                },
                'replaceText': replacement,
            }
        })

    service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=document_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Assuming event contains 'filename' and 'replacements'
    filename = event['filename']
    replacements = event['replacements']

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_INFO, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
    
    docs_service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    
    # Copy the template document
    template_id = ''
    copy_title = filename
    drive_response = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=template_id, body={'name': copy_title}).execute()
    new_document_id = drive_response.get('id')

    # Replace placeholders in the new document
    replace_placeholders(docs_service, new_document_id, replacements)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'New document created with ID: {new_document_id}')
    }
```

and this is the error I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'google'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "bd4a1871-8feb-4d2d-b07a-01216ad5514a",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I tried to add dependency using a Lambda Layer but it still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give the OS on which you installed the package for lambda creation? Lambda runs on Linux based so its advised to add python packages zip created in linux

Comment: @HanumanthReddyAredla I am using windows OS.

Comment: possible two issues that can cause this
1. Issue in Creating the layer correctly. I believe you are aware of but any how sharing the link for reference for instructions. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65770779/12045913
2. Creating the zip file by getting the package in linux OS. You can use docker, instructions link here. 
https://medium.com/simform-engineering/creating-lambda-layers-made-easy-with-docker-a-developers-guide-3bcfcf32d7c3

Comment: @HanumanthReddyAredla Thank you! I found that I created the layer in a wrong structure causing it unable to read. Thanks for the help!