# How to make a HTTP rest call in AWS lambda using python?

Tags: aws-lambda

To make an http call using python my way was to use `requests`.

But `requests` is not installed in lambda context. Using `import requests` resulted in module is not found error.

The other way is to use the provided lib `from botocore.vendored import requests`. But this lib is deprecated by AWS.

I want to avoid to package dependencies within my lambda zip file.

What is the smartest solution to make a REST call in python based lambda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution 1)**

Since `from botocore.vendored import requests` is deprecated the recomended way is to install your dependencies.

```
$ pip install requests
```

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://...')
```

See also. https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/

> But you have to take care for packaging the dependencies within your lambda zip.

**Solution 2)**

My preferred solution is to use `urllib`. It's within your lambda execution context.

https://repl.it/@SmaMa/DutifulChocolateApplicationprogrammer

```
import urllib.request
import json

res = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(
        url='http://asdfast.beobit.net/api/',
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
        method='GET'),
    timeout=5)

print(res.status)
print(res.reason)
print(json.loads(res.read()))
```

**Solution 3)**

Using `http.client`, it's also within your lambda execution context.

https://repl.it/@SmaMa/ExoticUnsightlyAstrophysics

```
import http.client

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection('fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net')
connection.request('GET', '/api/Books')

response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.read().decode())
```